# php preg_match find number from varriable

Tags: php, preg-match

I am  trying to find laptop's CPU GHZ.

The string is:

```
Processor: Intel Core i5 5200U 2.2GHz
```

But the **Intel Core i5 5200U** can be different string. 
But I need to find only GHz. 
I can't do it because **Intel Core i5 5200U** is changing on every laptop.

Comment: `/Processor: .+ ([^\s]+)GHz/`

Comment: worked. add your answer ;)

Comment: i have written an answer

Comment: i have marked as answer =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use such regex

```
/Processor: .+ ([^\s]+)GHz/
```

[**Demo and explanation**](https://www.regex101.com/r/jY5sW4/1)